# JQUERY tipsy replacing tittle attribute to original-tittle

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using tipsy plugin of jquery.  I have used localisation also.

In my project I have an image having `tittle = '@Language.ClickToEdit'`
like `<img  tittle = '@Language.ClickToEdit' id = $([id])>`

when first time the page is displayed i am getting `<img original- tittle = '@Language.ClickToEdit' id = $([id])>` this original-title in place of tittle.

No tooltip message is displayed at first time.

When I clicks the image after that i am able to see tooltip message.

So, is there any way to overcome this orginal-title attribute. my tittle is dynamically changing for respective languages.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the attribute name is `title` not `tittle`.

The quotation below is from http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/

> Tipsy needs to erase any existing value for an element's title
>   attribute in order to suppress the browser's native tooltips. It is
>   stashed in the element's original-title attribute in case you need to
>   retrieve it later.
>
> As of version 0.1.4, the tooltip text is recomputed on every hover
>   event so updating the title attribute will have the expected effect.

It looks like you can't eliminate the `original-title` attribute while using the Tipsy plugin.
Consider changing the title to corresponding language values **before** initialising of tipsy.

Comment: could u please giveme an example forhow to change the title to corresponding language values before initialising of tipsy.
Also Why the tooltip is not displayed first time the browser appears thhoug it is working fine after clicking it .

Comment: I can't show you an example without your code. Show me what have you done. If you can't share the page, consider doing it here http://jsfiddle.net/